# How is scroll position saved when the screen is rotated?

Tags: android

I am saving an `ArrayList` of objects by overriding `onSaveInstanceState` in an activity. In the `onCreate` method of that activity I restored the list of objects that I saved.

Here is the code from the activity -

```
public class MovieListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;
private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
private MovieListAdapter movieListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_list);
    RecyclerView moviesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movie_list_rv);

    if (savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.containsKey("movieList")) {
        movies = createMovies(30);
    } else {
        // Restoring only the list of movies not the scroll position
        movies = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("movieList");
    }

    movieListAdapter = new MovieListAdapter(this, movies);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    moviesRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieListAdapter);
    moviesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, final int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    movies.addAll(createMovies(20));
                    movieListAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(totalItemsCount, movies.size() - 1);
                }
            };
            handler.post(r);
        }
    };
    moviesRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Saving only the list of movies
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("movieList", movies);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private ArrayList<Movie> createMovies(int numberOfMovies) {
    ArrayList<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfMovies; i++) {
        movieList.add(new Movie("Hello", new DateTime("2017-03-16T01:20"), "This is a very good movie"));
    }
    Log.i("Create", "create called");
    return movieList;
}
```

}

When I rotate the screen not only the objects but also the scroll position is restored.

1. How is the scroll position getting saved and restored even though I did not save it?
2. Is the scroll position automatically saved when `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is called?

Screenshots of emulator before and after rotating - before rotating

[image]

& after rotating

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: views save their own state. The list view saves which item is the first visible one.

Comment: @njzk2 But, isn't activity recreated whenever the screen is rotated? Can you point me to some resources where I can read about how the view saves its state?

Comment: it is recreated, but the state of the views is still saved and restored automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I should have read the documentation with more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your activity begins to stop, the system calls the onSaveInstanceState() method so your activity can save state information with a collection of key-value pairs. The default implementation of this method saves transient information about the state of the activity's view hierarchy, such as the text in an EditText widget or the scroll position of a ListView widget

for more information refer to **Saving and restoring activity state** in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html